# Why is my custom JPanel not being painted / repainted even though I'm painting from the Event Queue and overwriting paintComponent()?

Tags: java, swing, paint

I trying to make my first Swing application and i cannont for the life of me figure out why nothing is painted and I only get an empty Window.

I am using `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` to start the AWT Event Queue Thread, in my Controller I am using a `SwingWorker doInBackground()` for my Main Loop, processing my Model code.

I use events to pass changes from my model to the controller who then puts it in a concurrent change queue which the View uses to update itself.

I have been at this for hours and still no idea why it won't paint. I'm painting from the Event Queue Thread, I'm overriding `paintComponent` and call `super.paintComponent()` like it's supposed to be done (to my knowledge).

The sys.outs indicate that the rest of the application logic seem to work fine.

I tried to cut down the code to the necessities but it's still a wall of text, sorry for that. It should compile though.

```
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                Controller controller = new Controller("Swing MVC Test Application");
                controller.start();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Model

```
import javax.swing.event.EventListenerList;

public class Model {

    private EventListenerList listeners = new EventListenerList();
    private int[][] someChange = new int[][]{
            { 0,1},
            { 2,3},
            {4,5}
    };
    private int gameLoopCounter = 0;

    public Model(ModelChangeListener listener) {
        listeners.add(ModelChangeListener.class, listener);
    }

    protected synchronized void notifyListeners(ModelChangeEvent event) {
        for (ModelChangeListener l : listeners.getListeners(ModelChangeListener.class))
            l.receiveModelChange(event);
    }

    public void nextGameLoopIteration() {
        notifyListeners(new ModelChangeEvent(this, someChange[gameLoopCounter]));
        gameLoopCounter++;
    }

}
```

Controller

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;

public class Controller implements ModelChangeListener {
    private static final int QUEUE_SIZE = 20;

    private Model model;
    private View view;

    public final BlockingQueue<ModelChangeEvent> changeQueue;

    public Controller(String title) {
        this.changeQueue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<ModelChangeEvent>(QUEUE_SIZE) ;
        this.model = new Model(this);
        this.view = new View(this, title);
    }
    public void start() {
        SwingWorker<Void, Void> mainLoop = new SwingWorker<Void, Void>() {
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
                while (true) {
                    if (1 == 0) return null;

                    model.nextGameLoopIteration();
                }
            }
        };
        mainLoop.execute();

        long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
        while (true){
            time += View.MILLIS_PER_LOOP;
            try {
                view.processModelUpdates();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                Thread.sleep(Math.max(0, time - System.currentTimeMillis()));
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void receiveModelChange(ModelChangeEvent e) {
        try {
            this.changeQueue.put(e);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

View

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class View extends JPanel {
    public static final int MILLIS_PER_LOOP = 1000;
    private static final int CELLSIZE = 40;

    private Controller controller;
    private myPanel myPanel;

    private ModelChangeEvent currentModelState;

    public View(Controller controller, String title) throws HeadlessException {
        this.controller = controller;

        this.setSize(1500,1100);

        initFrame(title);
    }

    private void initFrame(String title) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame(title);
        frame.setContentPane(this);
        frame.setSize(1600, 1200);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public void processModelUpdates() throws InterruptedException {
        this.currentModelState = this.controller.changeQueue.poll(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        if (currentModelState != null) {
            // do some processing....
            this.repaint();
        }

    }
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        // draw something
        g.drawOval(currentModelState.getMovementExample()[0],
                currentModelState.getMovementExample()[1],
                CELLSIZE, CELLSIZE);
    }
}
```

Event Listener Interface and Class

```
import java.util.EventListener;

public interface ModelChangeListener extends EventListener {
          void  receiveModelChange( ModelChangeEvent e);
}
```

Event Listener Class

```
import java.util.EventObject;

public class ModelChangeEvent extends EventObject {
    private int[] movementExample;

    public int[] getMovementExample() {
        return movementExample;
    }

    public ModelChangeEvent(Object source, int[] change) {
        super(source);
        movementExample  = change;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getSource() {
        return super.getSource();
    }
}
```

Comment: For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). *"I tried to cut down the code to the necessities but it's still a wall of text, sorry for that."* No need for apologies. I'll just ignore it till it's cut down a **lot** more.

Comment: I gave it another shot but i'm guessing it's still too long...

Answer (score 0):

> I am using a SwingWorker doInBackground() for my Main Loop,

A couple of things stick out:

```
model.nextGameLoopIteration();
```

That is basically an infinite loop since you don't have a timing mechanism. For a game you would generally need a Thread.sleep(…) to allow the game to repaint itself and reset the game state.

Also, I actually see a second loop:

```
controller.start();
```

The above code is executed on the EDT.

In the start() method withing a while (true) loop you have:

```
Thread.sleep(Math.max(0, time - System.currentTimeMillis()));
```

So this is also an infinite loop which will cause the EDT to sleep, meaning it can't respond to events or repaint the GUI.

Not sure why you have two loops, but you definitely should not be sleeping on the EDT.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, I was under the impression that I need one loop in each thread to keep them alive, is that not the case? The thread.sleep in the EDT is supposed to be the timing mechanism you mentioned above. Should that be in the main loop then?

Comment: The EDT is always alive. All Swing components should be updated on the EDT. If you want to use a SwingWorker as the main loop, then yes, it should have the Thread.sleep(). However, the `nextGameLoopIteration()` method needs to execute on the EDT so the game state is updated on the EDT. This mean you would wrap that method in a SwingUtilities.invokeLater(). The other option is to use a Swing Timer to schedule the animation. Then you don't need any looping code. The Timer will just generate an event and you can invoke your next game loop since the Timer code is invoked on the EDT..

Comment: But I am updating on the EDT, view.processModelUpdate is reading from the concurrent queue and updating. Why does the nextGameLoopIteration have to be on the EDT, i'm assuming i am going to do the heavy lifting in here, potentially freezing the GUI. I have small paste here https://pastebin.com/Wf9XNJXU explaining how I understand it. Could you elaborate some more or do a minimal paste since I suppose that I haven't grasped the concept yet. Would be much appreciated.

Comment: Swing is single Threaded. As I understand it any changes in the state of the components need to be done on the EDT to prevent random errors. For example if you have some "heavy lifting" executing on a separate thread that has only updated the state of part of the model and for some reason Swing need to repaint the component, then the state of the component is not complete. The advice I have seen in the forums is that all updates to the model and view should be done on the EDT. I don't see any other code where you use InvokeLater() to place code on the EDT.

Comment: Read the Swing tutorial on [Concurrency](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more information.